# Can't properly disable flyspell in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, flyspell

I set up emacs to turn flyspell on by default for text mode using

```
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

I would like to disable it automatically in org mode files, and I did manage to disable it using a lambda function in the org mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode -1)))
```

This works, but the syntax highlight changes that flyspell did still remain, and interfere with org mode's syntax highlight. I also see in the minibuffer that flyspell does run when I visit that file, so apparently it is turned off only afterwards. How do I turn it off in such a way that would leave no trace of it in the org mode file, or better yet not run at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can selectively enable flyspell in text-mode hook by checking the major-mode. The following will enable flyspell in `text-mode` and its derived modes except `org-mode`

```
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                 (when (not (equal major-mode 'org-mode))
                                   (flyspell-mode t))))
```

Comment: You can probably simplify the lambda to `(lambda () (flyspell-mode (not (equal major-mode 'org-mode))))`.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for the suggestion however according to `flyspell-mode`'s documentation, when called from Lisp, flyspell-mode is enabled even when the `arg` is omitted or is `nil`.

Comment: Your solution is clearly better then. I tried it out briefly and it seemed to work despite what the documentation says but I didn't test it very thoroughly. And even if, we better stick to what the documentation says.

Comment: While this disables fylspell mode in org buffers, I'm still left with traces of its spell error highlights. In other words, it still disables it after flyspell does its thing. I managed to get rid of its highlights using fniessen's suggestion, so I suppose this solves my issue. If you modify the answer I'll accept it. I'm still curious if it's possible to make it so that flyspell doesn't start in org-mode buffers to begin with.

Comment: This is strange, for me with the above two lines `flyspell-mode` does not activate in the org buffers at all. Try `M-: text-mode-hook RET` what does it print? Also make sure you do not have `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)` in your init file.

Comment: The output of `M-: text-mode-hook RET` is `((lambda nil (if (not ...) (flyspell-mode t) (flyspell-delete-all-overlays))) text-mode-hook-identify)`

Comment: OK my bad, `M-:` did not give full output (the condition is shown as ellipsis). Maybe you should start `ielm` (`M-x ielm`) and then type `text-mode-hook` what value did it return?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question (remove the highlightings), the following call should do it:

```
(flyspell-delete-all-overlays)
```

However, are you really, really, really sure you want to disable flyspell in Org mode???  Is there a really, really, really good reason for that?

If yes, shouldn't you solve that one, instead of trying the above?

Comment: You seem to assume that flyspell is a "really, really, really" important feature in just about any use of org-mode. I assure you it is not. My org-mode file has names, mixed languages, abbreviations, and plenty of other things that I don't want to be spell checked. When these things are highlighted, org-mode syntax highlight doesn't stand out as much from the rest of the text, which reduces readability.

Comment: In such a case, I would either add your abbreviations and such either as Local Words or in your global dictionary. Of course, that does not solve mixed languages, indeed. But Flyspell is so interesting that I can't imagine not having it enabled in ALL my Org files. Better would be to disable that locally via the Local Variables.